# Cant define root route more than once in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing, route-constraint

I've got the following in my routes file:

```
scope :constraints => lambda{ |req| req.session[:user_id].present? } do
  root "users#show"  
end

scope :constraints => lambda{ |req| req.session[:admin_id].present? } do
  root "brands#index"  
end

root "sessions#new"
```

This code worked fine in Rails 3, but when I use it in Rails 4 I get the following error message:

> Invalid route name, already in use 'root' (ArgumentError).
>
> You may have defined two routes with the same name using the ':as' option

Is there a way round this? What has changed?

Comment: Is this the only code you have in your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10494

Comment: Thanks @vimsha! I will post the fix.

Comment: Rails 4.1.4 and this still persists. Blah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @vimsha pointed out, it's a [known issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10494) and in my case the best fix was to do the following:

```
scope :constraints => lambda{ |req| req.session[:user_id].present? } do
  match '/', to: "users#index", via: :get  
end

scope :constraints => lambda{ |req| req.session[:admin_id].present? } do
  match '/', to: "brands#index", via: :get  
end

root "sessions#new"
```

Alles im ordinem.